# awk key-value issue for array

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I meet a awk array issue, details as below:

```
[~/temp]$ cat test.txt
1
2
3
4
1
2
3
```

Then I want to count the frequency of the number.

```
[~/temp]$ awk 'num[$1]++;END{for (i in num){printf("%s\t%-s\n", num[i],i)|"sort -r -n -k1"} }' test.txt
1
2
3
2       3
2       2
2       1
1       4
```

As you see, why does the output of first 3 line '1 2 3' will come blank value?

Thank for your answer.

Comment: Did you Google about how can you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An awk statement consists of a *pattern* and related *action*. Omitted pattern matches every record of input. Omitted action is an alias to `{print $0}`, ie. output the current record, which is what you are getting. Looking at the first part of your program:

```
$ awk 'num[$1]++' file
1
2
3
```

Let's change that a bit to understand what happens there:

```
$ awk '{print "NR:",NR,"num["$1"]++:",num[$1]++}' file
NR: 1 num[1]++: 0
NR: 2 num[2]++: 0
NR: 3 num[3]++: 0
NR: 4 num[4]++: 0
NR: 5 num[1]++: 1
NR: 6 num[2]++: 1
NR: 7 num[3]++: 1
```

Since you are using *postfix operator* `num[$1]++` in the pattern, on records 1-4 it gets evaluated to 0 before it's value is incremented. Output would be different if you used the *prefix operator* `++num[$1]` which would first increment the value of the variable after which it would get evaluated and would lead to outputing every record of input, not just the last three, which you were getting.

Correct way would've been to use `num[$1]++` as an action, not as a pattern:

```
$ awk '{num[$1]++}' file
```

Comment: really appreciate~

Answer (score 0):

Put your "per line" part in `{}` i.e. `{ num[$1]++; }`

awk programs a a collection of `[pattern] { actions }` (the pattern is optional, the `{}` is not). Seems that in your case your line is being treated as the pattern.

Comment: yes, you are right , but how to explain the command when missing `{ }` ， I  want to know it more about the  significance of `{ }` in awk.